# An efficient way to cancel a mouseover event... read on to see why

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm in the process of authoring a completely client side web language reference site. A problem that I encountered today; I have a side panel that is a unordered list of terms and they have `onmouseover` event listeners. I decided it would be a good idea to add a delay prior to execution and cancel the event at run-time if the mouse was no longer over that element. This is what I've come up with but I feel there must be a better way.

```
var currentXCoordinate=0
var currentYCoordinate=0
var elementFromCurrentMousePosition=0
function trackCurrentMousePosition(event) {
    if (document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY).nodeName=="SPAN") {
        elementFromCurrentMousePosition=document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY).parentNode
    }
    else {
        elementFromCurrentMousePosition=document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)
    }
    return (currentXCoordinate=event.clientX, currentYCoordinate=event.clientY, elementFromCurrentMousePosition)
}
function initPreview(event, obj) {
    arg1=event
    arg2=obj
    setTimeout("setPreviewDataFields(arg1, arg2)", 100)
}
function setPreviewDataFields(event, obj) {
    if ('bubbles' in event) {
        event.stopPropagation()
    }
    else {
        event.cancelBubble=true
    }
    if (elementFromCurrentMousePosition!=obj) {
        return 0;
    }
```

The code goes on to do all the wonderful stuff I want it to do if execution wasn't cancelled by the previous if statement. The problem is this method is seeming to be really processor intensive.

To sum it up: on page load all my event listeners are registered, cursor position is being tracked by a `onmousemove` event. Applicable list items have a `onmouseover` event that calls the `initPreview` function which just waits a given period of time before calling the actual `setPreviewDataFields` function. If at run-time the cursor is no longer over the list element the function stops by `return 0`.

Sadly that's the best I could come up with. If anyone can offer up a better solution I would be very grateful.

Comment: You should take some time to properly format your code, and also provide some html. That would help a great deal.

Comment: Your code is missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `mouseout` to tell when the mouse leaves an element?  Running all of that code every time the mouse moves isn't ideal.

Also, you really shouldn't pass a string to `setTimeout` like that.  Instead, pass a function.  As a bonus, you can get rid of those evil global variables `arg1` and `arg2`.  With those being globals, I think you will run into issues if init gets called again before the timeout expires.

Comment: The problem I ran into trying to use mouseout it is the only way I could figure out to use mouseout to cancel execution when using a delay was by the cancelTimeout() method which meant I had to attach a global variable to the setTimeout() so that I could have an argument to pass. The problem that caused is the global variable for setTimeout would be overwritten every time the cursor moved over a new element. Causing the mouseout event to only cancel a subset of the events that should be canceled. I figured out what u meant about passing a string instead of fuction. Thanks for the tip.